# Use own documentation in Qt Creator help mode

Tags: qt, qt-creator

Qt Creator has the convenient feature that I can select any Qt class, press `F1` and the Qt documentation for that class opens (see second link below).

Now I would like to have the same functionality for my own classes which are already documented using Doxygen.

I've found the IMHO quite short documentation for the [Qt Help Framework](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthelp-framework.html) and [Qt Creator Help Mode](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-help.html). I've also already found the menu in Qt Creator where i could add more help files, but I didn't find anything about how to exactly define my Doxygen and then pack it into a Qt help file so that Qt Creator would find the correct link anchors etc.

Has anybody done this before and can help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set these doxyfile's variables:

```
GENERATE_QHP           = YES
QCH_FILE               = <project>.qch
QHP_NAMESPACE          = <namespace>
QHP_VIRTUAL_FOLDER     = doc
QHG_LOCATION           = qhelpgenerator
```

The ones in `<>` braces can be anything you want.

Comment: ok, so the right way would have been searching Doxygen's and not Qt's documentation? ;)

Comment: I'll try it sometime this week, so please don't wonder if I don't accept your question right away.